# Show that $f:\mathbb{R}\to H, f(t):=(\cosh(t), \sinh(t))$ is a bijection

Tags: analysis, trigonometry

Where $H:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:x\gt0, x^2-y^2=1\}$

I figured out that this is supposed to be the function of the positive branch of the Hyperbola. It would be a prove to show that the hyperbola has a parametric equation. Usually i would try to find an inverse function $g: H \to\mathbb{R}$ and would show that $f\circ g = \mathrm{id}_H $ and $g\circ f=\mathrm{id}_\mathbb{R}$. But i don't know how to find an inverse function in this case. I do know however that the inverse function of $\sinh(x)$ is $\operatorname{arsinh}(x)=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$ and of $\cosh(x)$ it is $\operatorname{arcosh}(x)=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})$. Could I use this somehow?

Comment: You can find an explicit inverse by cases depending on which of the two quadrants the pair $(x,y)$ lies in. With appropriate signage, the principal branches of the area hyperbolic functions will give you what you need on a per-quadrant basis

Comment: MathJax tip: use \ to render functions (and almost everything really): `\ln,\sinh,\cosh` and use `\operatorname{arsinh}` to render things not included in standard MarhJax

Comment: One more: use `\mathrm{id}` or `\newcommand{\id}{\operatorname{Id}}` and then using `\id` once you’ve declared the command will work.

Answer (score 1):

You've got:
$$
\cosh(t) := \frac{e^t + e^{-t}}{2}, \quad \sinh(t) := \frac{e^t - e^{-t}}{2}.
$$
Introducing some variables, we get:
$$
x := \frac{e^t + e^{-t}}{2}, \quad y := \frac{e^t - e^{-t}}{2}.
$$
So,
$$
x + y = e^t.
$$
Thus $\ln(x + y) = t$.  So, you can figure out if $\ln(x + y)$ is a bijection for $x^2 - y^2 = 1$.